# How do I make Timeout command from entrypoint in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, shell, dockerfile, timeout

I have been trying to run timeout command on my shellscript with time being passed as variabe through Dockerfile

This is my DokcerFile(sample)

```
FROM locustio/locust:1.2.3

ARG TIME_CHECK=15

COPY --chown=locust:locust ping.sh .

RUN echo  "Hello $TIME_CHECK"

RUN chown locust:locust /home/locust && chmod +x ./ping.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","-c", "timeout $TIME_CHECK ./ping.sh"]
```

Docker build happens successfully with below command and I can the value being passed correctly

```
docker build -t pingit --build-arg TIME_CHECK=10
```

When I do docker run it fails with following error

**Try 'timeout --help' for more information.**

I do understand this is because ENTRYPOINT is not recogninsing variable as such.

What am I doing wrong can you anyone help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docker reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg), you can only access `ARG` values at build-time.

To pass a value to the runtime environment variable, you can use `ENV` instruction:

```
FROM locustio/locust:1.2.3

ARG TIME_CHECK=15

# assign ENV from ARG
ENV TIME_CHECK=${TIME_CHECK}

COPY --chown=locust:locust ping.sh .

RUN echo  "Hello $TIME_CHECK"

RUN chown locust:locust /home/locust && chmod +x ./ping.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","-c", "timeout $TIME_CHECK ./ping.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `ENV TIME_CHECK=$TIME_CHECK` to your dockerfile after the `ARG` statement.

The issue is that `ARG` is at build time. If you need to use it as environment variable then you need to set the variable yourself